# Excel-VBA: Modul-Call does not work when called from code in "ThisWorkbook"

Tags: excel, vba

I call a modul upon save:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

With Sheets("Einstellungen")
    If .Cells(17, "C").Value = "ja" Then
        Call ModulCheck.CheckForEmptyCells '<- Idk why this is not working. Call the Sub from somewhere else and all is nice.
    End if
End With
End Sub
```

The called Modul (see below) then fails (i.e., stopps running) in `For Each`:

```
Sub CheckForEmptyCells() 'check for empty cells
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim c As Range

With Sheets("Probeninventar")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each c In .Range("E8:G" & LastRow & ",W" & LastRow).Cells
        If IsEmpty(c) Then
            If IsEmpty(Sheets("Einstellungen").Range("M5").Value) Then
                Sheets("Einstellungen").Range("M5").Value = "Datensatz unvollständig in: " & c.Row
            End if
        End if
    Next c
End With
End Sub
```

Calling the Module from a Worksheet does work. Calling it from "This Workbook" upon save does not work. Why?

Comment: What does "Does not work mean". Is there an error. Is the code not executing. If it's not executing have you added a breakpoint (F9 while the cursor is on a line of code, then run the code) to insure that your BeforeSave is being executed, and then later on if the `CheckForEmptyCells()` subroutine is being executed?

Comment: `Why? Is it because there are two Withscrewed up?` - cannot be because of this, the two `With` are in different scopes (subs).

Comment: "Does not work" means that the code stops runing at the line with the `For Each` Loop starting. Which runs properly when called from somewhere else...

Comment: @Bendaua - just for a test, can you write `.Range("E8:G" & LastRow & ",W" & LastRow).Select:Stop` before the for loop and share what is happening?

Comment: That's the goal of `Stop` keyword. I think @Vityata want to know if some cells are selected, and which ones.

Comment: @VincentG - exactly that was my point. @Bendaua - If the declared cells are selected, start pressing `F8` on the keyboard and see what is happening.

Comment: Rigth. I did that and the code ran sucessfully step by step. (?!)  Letting it run by saving leads to a fail again. However, I think @Vityata might be on the correct path: I changed `... & ",W" & ...` into `... & ",W8:W" & ...` and now it works.

Comment: Arg. having said that, this stopped working, too. May it be helpfull that I am using Rubberduck? The `Locals`Window states c=Nothing on stop.

Comment: Is the last row higher than an integer can handle? That would make it not work - with an overflow error.

Comment: Good idea. But the LastRow Number is "157".

Comment: Looking at your last comment - I'm thinking `c = Nothing` isn't the same as `IsEmpty(c)` which might not cause an error but would return FALSE causing the block not to execute?